# Adding watchOS 2.0 to project with existing watchOS 1.0 app causes weird compile error

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7, watchos-2

We have an app built for iOS 8.4 with watchOS1 on Xcode 6.4.  That all works fine, compiles, builds and runs no problem.  With the coming of Xcode 7, and watchOS2, we wanted to add a watchOS2 app as a target to our project.  After just adding the target, and running a build command, we get the following error:

**No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s arm64).**

I had a look, and we have NO i386 even mentioned anywhere - the App has "Valid Architecture (armv7, armv7s, arm64), the watchOS1.0 extension and app have the same Valid Architecture as the iPhone app., watchOS2.0 App and Extension has the valid architecture armv7k.

I have tried the following with the same error :

1)  I have completely deleted the watchOS1 app, and created a watchOS2 app - same arch error.
2)  I have tried "Build Active Architecture" YES/NO on all targets - same arch error.
3)  I have tried adding i386 as a valid Architecture, and it builds, but when it tries to launch the simulator, I get a **The operation couldn’t be completed. (LaunchServicesError error 0.)** error from the simulator.
4)  I created a brand new project with both watchOS1 and watchOS2 Targets - NO PROBLEM in compiling.
5)  Changing iOS Deployment Target from 7.0 to 9.0 - same arch error.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong here.  I noticed the same question on the Apple Developers Forum, with no answer..

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT!  Do NOT include armv7k for watch2.0 apps and watch2.0 extensions - instead put there $(ARCHS_STANDARD) .   LaunchServicesError is caused by not having the IDENTICAL bundle-ids in the project, and that must match WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier in the plist file.

Comment: It is added by default. I can't delete it. Xcode 8.1

Comment: Updating legacy lib solved the problem.